# Given $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$ what type is this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, robotics

With $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, what type of matrix is $A$?

$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & a  & -b \\
-a & 0  & c \\
b  & -c & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

So far I've tested $A$ for several types, I know that $A$ is non-orthogonal, obviously skew-symmetric and singular, as it's determinant equals $0$ and there is no chance to get an inverse.

But nothing is related to the $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$ condition, any ideas?

Comment: Why should any matrix be " special " ?

Comment: @mick thanks for the quick reply, but I don't get your question?, is it about the nature of my question? why should this matrix belong to a "special" type?

Comment: Yes. Not Every matrix has an important property. Not sure about this one though.

Comment: Well, it's a unit vector in the 3d subspace of skew symmetric matrices -
 equipped with the given norm - among all $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: $A^3=-A=A^T\,$ if you consider that "special".

Comment: By @dxiv comment, it means minimum polynomial is $x^3+x=x(x^2+1)=0$ that means it's eigenvalues  are $0,i,-i$. Now we can say it's a special matrix!

Comment: You can see that using Jyrki's argument, too, since the eigenvalues of a rotation matrix are $1=e^{0},e^{i\theta}$, and $e^{-i\theta}$. @Amin235 (Just a neat agreement between two points of view.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews we have $A^{3^n}=(-1)^n\,A$. How does it  interpret by Jyrki's argument. Thanks

Comment: One special property is $A^{n+2} = -A^n$, making it a periodic matrix, i.e. $A^5=A$. Also the Drazin and Penrose inverses are given by the transpose $A^+=A^T$. Its eigenvalues are $\{-i, 0, +i\}$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\{(A^2-iA)v, a, (A^2+iA)v\}$ where $v$ can be any vector such that $Av\ne 0$

Comment: I just noticed $A^2 = -AA^T$

Comment: @Hans That follows directly from $\,A=-A^T\,$, and does not require $a^2+b^2+c^2=1\,$.

Comment: @Amin235 When $A^{n+2}=-A^n$ for all $n>0$ it means that
$$ (\theta A)+\frac{(\theta A)^3}{3!}+\frac{(\theta A)^5}{5!}+\cdots=A(\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{3!}+\frac{\theta^5}{5!}-\cdots)=A\sin\theta.$$ Similarly the even degree terms give something like $A^2\cos\theta $ except for an error in $A^0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I appreciate for your comment.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, sure thing. Haven't noticed, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have not read as much algebra to make sense of Jyrkis answer: in other words it is "rotation around an axis" (vector cross product) by the vector $(c,b,a)$. If you remember from linear algebra $$(x,y,z)^T \times (c,b,a)^T$$
Now try calculating $$\begin{bmatrix}0&a&-b\\-a&0&c\\b&-c&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$
Unless I am tired and wrote it wrong, the results should be the same!

In other words it is a **matrix representation of cross product by a vector**.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like $A$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $\vec{x}\mapsto \vec{x}\times (c,b,a)$. Therefore it is the so called infinitesimal generator for the group of rotations around the axis $\vec{n}=(c,b,a)$ (a unit vector!). We get those rotation matrices (in the right handed direction) using the exponential
$$R(\theta)=e^{\theta A},$$
where matrix exponential is defined by the power series
$$
e^X=I_3+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}X^n.
$$
Of course, $\theta$ is the angle of rotation. If $\vec{n}$ were not a unit vector, the rotations would go at angular speed $\omega=||\vec{n}||$.

Don't know if this makes the matrices special in any way :-(

---

Basically you are looking at the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3,\Bbb{R})$. This is in a sense the reason cross products appear frequently when one studies the mechanics of rotations.